# How can I select rows from one DataFrame, where a part of the row's index is in another DataFrame's index and meets certain criteria?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have two DataFrames. `df` provides a lot of data. `test_df` describes whether certain tests have passed or not. I need to select from `df` only the rows where the tests have not failed by looking up this info in `test_df`. So far, I'm able to reduce my `test_df` to `passed_tests`. So, what's left is to select only the rows from `df` where the relevant part of the row index is in `passed_tests`. How can I do that?

**Updates:**

- test_db doesn't haven't unique rows. Where there are duplicate rows (and there may be more than 1 duplicate), the test that was the most positive takes priority. i.e True > Ok > False.

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


index = [np.array(['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux', 'qux']), np.array(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b'])]
data = np.array(['False', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'Ok', 'False'])
columns = ["Passed?"]
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
print test_df

index = [np.array(['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux', 'qux', 'qux']),
         np.array(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']),
         np.array(['1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2'])]
data = np.random.randn(8, 2)
columns = ["X", "Y"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
print df

passed_tests = test_df.loc[test_df['Passed?'].isin(['True', 'Ok'])]
print passed_tests
```

**df**

```
                X         Y
foo a 1  0.589776 -0.234717
      2  0.105161  1.937174
    b 1 -0.092252  0.143451
      2  0.939052 -0.239052
qux a 1  0.757239  2.836032
      2 -0.445335  1.352374
    b 1  2.175553 -0.700816
      2  1.082709 -0.923095
```

**test_df**

```
     Passed?
foo a   False
    a    True
    b   False
    b   False
qux a   False
    b      Ok
    b   False
```

**passed_tests**

```
      Passed?
foo a    True
qux b      Ok
```

**required solution**

```
                X         Y
foo a 1  0.589776 -0.234717
      2  0.105161  1.937174
qux b 1  2.175553 -0.700816
      2  1.082709 -0.923095
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `method='ffill'`, then check values by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (test_df.reindex(df.index, method='ffill'))
        Passed?
foo a 1    True
      2    True
    b 1   False
      2   False
qux a 1   False
      2   False
    b 1      Ok
      2      Ok

mask = test_df.reindex(df.index, method='ffill').isin(['True', 'Ok'])['Passed?']
print (mask)
foo  a  1     True
        2     True
     b  1    False
        2    False
qux  a  1    False
        2    False
     b  1     True
        2     True
Name: Passed?, dtype: bool

print (df[mask])
                X         Y
foo a 1 -0.580448 -0.168951
      2 -0.875165  1.304745
qux b 1 -0.147014 -0.787483
      2  0.188989 -1.159533
```

EDIT:

For remove duplicates here is the easier use:

- get columns from `MultiIndex` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
- [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) - `Passed?` column descending, first and second ascending
- [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) - keep only first value
- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for MultiIndex back
- [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for remove index names

```
test_df = test_df.reset_index()
                 .sort_values(['level_0','level_1', 'Passed?'], ascending=[1,1,0])
                 .drop_duplicates(['level_0','level_1'])
                 .set_index(['level_0','level_1'])
                 .rename_axis([None, None])
print (test_df)
      Passed?
foo a    True
    b   False
qux a   False
    b      Ok
```

Another solution is simplier - sorting first and then `groupby` with `first`:

```
test_df = test_df.sort_values('Passed?', ascending=False)
                 .groupby(level=[0,1])
                 .first()
print (test_df)
      Passed?
foo a    True
    b   False
qux a   False
    b      Ok
```

EDIT1:

Convert values to [ordered Categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#sorting-and-order).

```
index = [np.array(['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux', 'qux']), np.array(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b'])]
data = np.array(['False', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'Acceptable', 'False'])
columns = ["Passed?"]
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
#print (test_df)

cat = ['False', 'Acceptable','True']
test_df["Passed?"] = test_df["Passed?"].astype('category', categories=cat, ordered=True)
print (test_df["Passed?"])
foo  a         False
     a          True
     b         False
     b         False
qux  a         False
     b    Acceptable
     b         False
Name: Passed?, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [False < Acceptable < True]

test_df = test_df.sort_values('Passed?', ascending=False).groupby(level=[0,1]).first()
print (test_df)
          Passed?
foo a        True
    b       False
qux a       False
    b  Acceptable
```

Comment: Your code works! However, I then found out my test_df has duplicate rows where a test might have been repeated! It doesn't matter if the test has failed, as long as it's passed once. So, I tried using passed_tests to create the mask, but then it got True against every row.

Comment: Can you add sample data with repeating with desired output? But if values are duplicated, the best is remove duplicates. because is more possible solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Edited my question. Sample data now has a duplicate. Desired output is still the same.

Comment: so if in some duplicates is at least one `True` or `Ok`, output is True? And if multiple `False`, output is False?

Comment: Or if duplicate, need keep only first row, all another has to be removed?

Comment: If at least one True or OK, output is True.

Comment: Super, for better testing I use `index = [np.array(['foo', 'foo','foo','foo', 'qux', 'qux', 'qux']),
         np.array(['a','a', 'b','b', 'a', 'b', 'b'])]
data = np.array(['False','True', 'False', 'False','False', 'Ok', 'False'])
columns = ["Passed?"]
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
print (test_df)`

Comment: Great! Updated my question to match!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137158/discussion-between-bluprince13-and-jezrael).

Comment: I assume you don't get notified if I put something in the chatroom. Basically, the problem is that my categories don't sort alphabetically - for example if I had True, Acceptable, and False. Any ideas? Is it worth raising a separate question for how to deal with that?

Comment: Yes, you can use categorical. give me a sec.